# Error while opening tex files in gedit

Tags: gedit, character-set

I use 5.8.5 version of notepad++. The .tex file that I have edited on notepad++ could not be opened on gedit. The error I get is "character set could not be recognized"

Comment: what charset does npp uses? default is ANSI, but you use an other? Try it with UTF-8...

Comment: I tried UTF-8, but the tex file refuses to compile. Then I tried with `UTF-8 without BOM`, but then strange, hex, characters appear in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to try (from the commandline):

Firstly:

`fromdos filename.tex`

(requires the tofrodos package).

Secondly:

`iconv -c -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 filename.tex > filename-copy.tex`

That should remove any characters not compatible with UTF-8.

(You should also follow the advice in the other answer about putting `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in your .tex source.)

Answer (score 1):

My latex files are all utf8 and compile on windows and on linux.

I would use `UTF-8 without BOM`

and add

`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

in the main file to inform the `pdflatex` or `latex` command that the content is UTF8